# CodeIgniter Undefined Property Error

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a table in my app named admin and I'm using the code below to select a record based off of submitted email and password. I'm getting "undefined property stdclass" errors for first_name, last_name and admin_role. I've triple checked and those are the names of the columns in my table. What am I doing wrong? I am autoloading the database and session libraries. Is it okay to set session data in a model?

Model Code:

```
public function can_sign_in() {
    $this->db->select('admin_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'admin_role');
    $this->db->where('admin_email', $this->input->post('admin_email'));
    $this->db->where('admin_password', md5($this->input->post('admin_password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('admin');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $admin[] = array(
                'admin_id' => $row->admin_id,
                'first_name' => $row->first_name,
                'last_name' => $row->last_name,
                'admin_role' => $row->admin_role
            );
          $this->session->set_userdata($admin);
       }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $this->db->select('admin_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'admin_role');
```

`select` only takes 2 parameters.  A string with with the fields to select, and a boolean saying if it should escape the string with backticks or not.

You're passing 4 parameters.  You want to pass just one, a string with the comma separated fields:

```
 $this->db->select('admin_id, first_name, last_name, admin_role');
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Can't believe I did not notice that from the documentation. Guess I need more coffee. :)

Comment: @RichCoy: I was looking at your code for a few minutes when I finally noticed that.  :-P